# creating list/tuple from string

Tags: python, list, loops

Sorry if this has been asked,I wasnt able to find it. I am building a slackbot and was looking to be able to loop through inputted data. The user would entered in IDs and the script would loop through those ids and return values. I am able to get it working if a single ID is entered but I was looking to have it search multiple IDs at once.

Entered in slack

```
@SlackBot search id1,id2,id3
```

I tried to enter the info from the chat into a list separated by a comma but python treats every character as a new asset in the list. (i,d,1, ,i,d,2,..)
I was able to have the data entered into a dictionary and when printed it shows as

```
[id1,id2,id3]
```

So i tried to loop through the dictionary but it treats that string as one object and doesnt loop.

```
def assetSearch(enteredID): 
    idList =[enteredID.upper()]
    searchedIDs = list()
    for eid in idList:
        print(eid) # This is here to see what its looking at
        for k, v in Content.items():
            if v['AssetID'] == eid:
```

the current print(eid) prints [id1,id2,id3] instead of id1, then id2.

Could someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: Take out the brackets around `enteredID.upper()`  You have a nested list, you don't want that

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried idList =enteredID.upper() and it prints out i,d,1,i,d,2,i,d,3 at the print(eid)

Comment: Then use `split(',')`

Comment: Thanks so much, i knew it was some stupidly simple like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do

`idList = enteredID.upper().split(",")`

Comment: Thanks so much, i knew it was some stupidly simple like this.